# build an string of different language and code page

Tags: c#, .net, string, globalization, codepages

I need to build an string made up of farsi charachter english and number
farsi char should have code page of arabic (windows-1256)
for example
9 character of space +numer of 3 digit +name of person in farsi with length pf 30 which has spaces befor it to becom 30 length char + etc
"---------111---------------------سارا میری"
When I show the string in messagebox the order of string is not what I want

What should I do to get the above result?

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out how Uniscribe does things.

Answer (score 0):

> the order of string is not what I want

You mean order of the words in the string itself?

Farsi is Right-To-Left Language so you probably need RTL text directionality

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh376txk(v=vs.71).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1689bxh(v=vs.71).aspx